# Can be no less than or cannot be no less than

Tags: word-usage

Which is correct, A or B ?

A)I can be no less than genuine or B) I cannot be no less than genuine

Answer (score 2):

A) is correct. B) is incorrect because it has a double negative; it would however  be grammatically correct to say

*I cannot be less than genuine* which conveys almost exactly the same meaning as A) - the difference between the two being that of immediacy vs. permanence.